# Running Chef cookbooks on ExaData

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, rhel, role, exadata

I am trying to run a Chef Cookbook on an ExaData server and I'm running into issues. I was able to bootstrap my ExaData servers. However when I run chef-client on the target nodes, I get an [error like this](https://gist.github.com/predatorian3/5831515). Then I went back and did a [verbose output of the error](https://gist.github.com/predatorian3/5831599), and still don't have any idea of what the issue is. I am able to `ping`, `traceroute`, and `nc` to and from the ExaData server to the Chef Server. None of the files transfer from the cookbook, or none of the files download from the remote Zabbix repository. The Chef run completes the role, and recipes but nothing is installed. Is there something different about ExaData from regular RHEL distributions that would cause issues?

--EDIT - 2013-07-15--

From looking at a ["successful" chef-client run](https://gist.github.com/predatorian3/6002305) on a regular RHEL 6.2 OS, where as ExaData runs RHEL 5.8, I saw fewer errors. There does seem to be a lot of libraries missing from ExaData in order to run chef-client. From what I have heard, and read in other posts, was that ExaData is a stripped version of RHEL 5.8, using only what is needed to run databases.

Comment: What are the versions of your Chef server and client?

Comment: My chef-client that is bootstrapped is 10.24.0 and my chef-server is running 0.10.8.5. My knife version is also 10.24.0. I try to stay away form using the omnibus installer unless its from a bootstrap or setting up my Server.

Comment: From reading through the verbose output, and thinking real hard,I see that Chef threw a bunch of exceptions. I will test on a regular RHEL system and compare against the ExaData system. I've heard rumors that ExaData uses a stripped down version of RHEL 5.8 just to do database functions. Maybe it is missing certain libraries and components that regular RHEL has and uses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to a comment on the [Chef IRC Logs](http://community.opscode.com/chat/chef/2012-11-02#id-226883) the 404 message is because the client is attempting to use a feature that your server version doesn't support.

If you add the setting `enable_reporting false` to your client.rb file it should disable the request to the /reports URL.

Comment: I changed that option in the /etc/chef/client.rb on the ExaData server, but still ran into [some errors](https://gist.github.com/predatorian3/5850790). I have no 404, everything is now 200, but the cookbook still isn't running properly. I'm looking into running `shef` to try and diagnose the problem. If I were to add the `break` statements, would it stop the recipe entirely, or would it just "pause" like a batch script would?

Comment: After doing a lot of other reading, and thinking, Oracle Linux that is ran on ExaData doesn't contain a lot of other libraries that Chef-Client relies on and thus doesn't work. I learned this trying to complete some other tasks that were failing as well because of this.